# Change dotplot scale color

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

With the following:

```
data(mtcars)
attach(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, color = cyl)
```

It generates a blue scale dot graph.

[image]

I would like to keep the same but change the colour scale, for example to a red colour scale instead of blue. Is it possible? I have to declare two variables under color? If so I do not know the syntax.

Comment: No need for `data(mtcars)` (this command actually does nothing in this case). There’s also no need for `attach(mtcars)`, and you should never use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `scale_color_gradient`:

```r
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, color = cyl) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "red4", high = "tomato")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works! In the meantime I solved also on my own doing the following: `Grafico <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, color = cyl)            

print(Grafico + scale_colour_gradient(low = "darkolivegreen1", high = "darkolivegreen"))`